# How can I make it so each instance in my node-group module use a specific security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

```
module "self_managed_node_group" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws//modules/self-managed-node-group"

  name                = "separate-self-mng"
  cluster_name        = aws_eks_cluster.eks.id
  cluster_version     = "1.22"
  cluster_endpoint    = aws_eks_cluster.eks.endpoint
  cluster_auth_base64 = aws_eks_cluster.eks.certificate_authority[0].data

  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnet_ids = [
    module.vpc.private_subnets[0],
    module.vpc.private_subnets[1],
    module.vpc.private_subnets[2],
  ]
  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.node-sg[0].id,
    aws_security_group.node-sg[1].id,
    aws_security_group.node-sg[2].id
  ]

  min_size     = 3
  max_size     = 6
  desired_size = 3

  key_name            = aws_key_pair.bastion_auth.id
  security_group_name = "node-sg"

  launch_template_name = aws_launch_template.node.id
  instance_type        = "t2.micro"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "node-sg" {

  count = var.azs
  name   = "node-security-group-${count.index}"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress {
    protocol    = "tcp"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.bastion-sg[count.index].id]
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = -1
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

I have 3 separate security groups: *node-sg[0]*. *node-sg[1]* and *node-sg[2]*. Right now in my **self_managed_node_group** module, the only way I could add all 3 was like-so:

```
vpc_security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.node-sg[0].id,
    aws_security_group.node-sg[1].id,
    aws_security_group.node-sg[2].id
  ]
```

This obviously assigns all three security groups to each node that gets deployed. What I want instead, is my first node that gets created to use *node-sg[0]*, my second node to use *node-sg[1]* and my third node to use *node-sg[2]* but I can't figure out how to make that work

Comment: The code you presented should work exactly as you want. There is no reason why `security_groups = [aws_security_group.bastion-sg[count.index].id]` would result in all groups added. Which means that this is not your real code.

Comment: @Marcin Apologies, I completely misunderstood what my issue was. I thought it was a security group issue, but it's because of my node group module. I originally had 1 security group for all nodes, but created 3 SGs instead. My current code that I updated was the only way I could figure out how to supply all 3 SGs to my node group, but all it does is add all 3 SGs to each node. Is there any way to make it so node 1 gets security group 1, node 2 gets security group 2 etc

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear. You don't show how and where you even use `vpc_security_group_ids` to result in your issue.

Comment: @Marcin I updated the code of my original post and included my my `self_managed_node_group` module, that's where my `vpc_security_group_ids` is used. This module deploys 3 nodes and I was wondering if there's a way to assign a specific security group to each node that gets deployed, instead of one security group getting assigned to the entire node group as a whole

Comment: But what is the source code of the module? Where in the module do you use `vpc_security_group_ids`? You haven't show the code of module where `vpc_security_group_ids` is used causing the issue.

Comment: @Marcin is my post bugged out? I added the code 30 minutes ago and it's showing the updated version, with the module on my end. I can try deleting it and asking as a new question

Comment: Ok. Now I think I understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you want, unless you **fork** and manually modify [self-managed-node-group](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/tree/v18.26.2/modules/self-managed-node-group) module.

As you can see in its [source code](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/v18.26.2/modules/self-managed-node-group/main.tf#L48):

```
security_group_ids = compact(concat([try(aws_security_group.this[0].id, ""), var.cluster_primary_security_group_id], var.vpc_security_group_ids))
```

there is no functionality to iterate over `var.vpc_security_group_ids` for individual nodes. `var.vpc_security_group_ids` is used as a whole list, and entire list is assigned to each node.